# Compile errors for C++ Battery Collector tutorial

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Sorry very noob question incoming, I have been working through the [C++ Battery Collector tutorial](https://youtu.be/ator4Vk4-FU?list=PLZlv_N0_O1gYup-gvJtMsgJqnEB_dGiM4&t=191) from Unreal and I am having some compile issue with the code in the tutorial.

I have followed along in Visual studio and when creating the accessor methods in the header file I used the Intelli sense to generate the corosponding class.

`Pickup.h`

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "Pickup.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class BATTERYCOLLECTOR_API APickup : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    APickup();

    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

    // Return the mesh for the pickup
    FORCEINLINE class UStaticMeshComponent* GetMesh() const { return PickupMesh; }

    // Return whether or not the pickup is active
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintPure, Category = "Pickup");  // <--- error in this line
    bool IsActive();

    // Allows other classes to safely change whether or not the pickup is active 
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "Pickup");
    void setActive(bool NewPickupState);

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

    //True when the pickup can be used, and false when pickup is deactivated
    bool bIsActive;

private:
    //Static mesh to represent the pickup in the level
    UPROPERTY(visibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Pickup", meta = (AllowPrivateAccess = "true"))
    class UStaticMeshComponent* PickupMesh;

};
```

`Pickup.cpp`

```
#include "Pickup.h"

// Sets default values
APickup::APickup()
{
    // Set this actor to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = false;

    // All pickups start active
    bIsActive = true;

    // Create the static mesh component
    PickupMesh = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("PickupMesh"));

}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void APickup::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

}

// Called every frame
void APickup::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

}

// Visual studio created this definition 
//APickup::UFUNCTION(BlueprintPure, Category)
//{
    //What is should go in here?
//}

// Returns active state
bool APickup::IsActive()
{
    return bIsActive;
}

// Changes active state
void APickup::setActive(bool NewPickupState)
{
    bIsActive = NewPickupState;
}
```

On the line where I added the comment `Visual studio created this definition` in the .cpp file this was the definition added by visual studio code but I am not sure what is should be used for and it is failing to compile without this. (This definition was not in the tutorial but VS wants me to add it.)

As far as I can see I have defined the methods for both the UFUNCTIONS however if I don't have the the generated definition I get compile errors in the unreal engine.

`D:/Unreal Projects/BatteryCollector/Source/BatteryCollector/Pickup.h(25)  : Error: Function return type: Missing variable type`

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong or missing?

Comment: @un yards Type the error message in your question instead of providing an image with the error.

Comment: Removed image and added text version.

Comment: `Pickup.h` - `UFUNCTION(BlueprintPure, Category = "Pickup");`

Comment: Never used Unreal-engine, but I notice that between SetActive and IsActive there is a difference, a semicolon before the bool of IsActive? Is it expected?

Comment: I have fixed that already, noticed it 2 mins ago. Still the same output though.

Comment: are you sure you made a clean build?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I'll leave the honor to you, I simply played "where's the difference" with the code.

Comment: No problem, thanks for you help. I will mess around with it and try and get it working.

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts didnt see OPs last comment before, though I am still convinced that the `;` is part of the problem.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 OP added the semicolon also to the other function. Please OP, remove both the semicolons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Unreal documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Reference/Functions/index.html):

```
UFUNCTION([specifier, specifier, ...], [meta(key=value, key=value, ...)])
ReturnType FunctionName([Parameter, Parameter, ...])
```

There is no `;` in that declaration and most likely that is the problem.

Note that in the course of editing the question you added a `;` also to the other declaration, but you should rather remove both.

PS: I post this as an answer in the hope of turning semi-spammy comments into something useful. I dont know Unreal and maybe this answer is wrong, then just let me know.

Comment: Yeah you were right, the unneeded semi colon. VS was wanting to add some extra definitions because the line was terminated.

Comment: This answer is correct. The UFUNCTION macro acts as a decorator which adds additional metadata to the function's declaration which is then used by Unreal's build tool and editor. Even though it's generally written on a separate line, it's part of the declaration and shouldn't be separated from it by a semicolon.